# how to put a captcha to facebook comments

Tags: facebook-comments

Is there any way to use some kind of captcha when we use the facebook comments app?

I had in my site the FB comments feature (integrated with a SMF forum) so every comment gets posted in the forum also, but this is like give the spammers a free candy...

Any Ideas on how to put a captcha of some kind for the fb comments?

pd: If needed my site www.desadaptados.net (sorry is a spanish based site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments plugin does not have a captcha option. So, what you will need to do is to not display the comments plugin until the viewer of the page to enters a captcha. Once the captcha is correctly identified, then you can add the comments plugin to the DOM and can be parsed by `FB.XFBML.parse()` to get it to be rendered.